# Как подключиться к raspberry pi по public ip

Tags: raspberry-pi, remote-access

Полный новичок в настройке сетей.

ПРоблема в следующем, корректно цепляюсь к распберри по локалке, но не могу присоединиться по публичному ip.

Публичный ip для всех машин в сети показан одинаковый, пусть это будет xx.yy.zzz.iii

соответственно в роутере резервирую локальный ip для распберри, 192.168.1.8, потом делаю проброс порта для этого ip

[image]

Протокол TCP, но роутер позволяет сделать ANY, пробовал и с ANY, результат не меняется.

Когда я пытаюсь присоединиться по remote ip я в поле для ip putty ввожу соответственно xx.yy.zzz.iii порт 22 и жму connect.

Вижу окно терминала, где показан запрос login as:

вводил юзеров пая, или любого другого, терминал мне предлагает ввести пароль для {user}@router.rn

[image]

пароли юзеров не работают

в итоге я предположил это файервол роутера, который должен меня пустить дальше (предположение основанное ни на чем), поэтому я поытался войти по логину-паролю роутера, что тоже не привело к результату.

Проверил фаервол роутера - все ограничения сняты.

Не понимаю, что за домен router.rn и почему меня не пускает дальше. Может я изначально делаю что то неправильно? Задавайте уточняющие вопросы, отвечу

Answer (score 1):

Возможно там у роутера свой ssh висит на 22 порту, сделайте проброс на другой внешний порт, например 2222.

Comment: Плюс надо еще убедиться, что публичный IP действительно находится на этом роутере.
Плюс заходить на него действительно снаружи, а не из этой же внутренней сети.